# Input text area field not allowing to insert more than 1 line

Tags: javascript

I have a text box, wherein 1 line of comma separated data is getting inserted successfully, but when clicked Enter to insert another similar line. It does nothing. It does not allow to add a new line of input data.

```html
<div class="formFields qP">
  <div> <textarea id="qPA" name="qP" placeholder="Hello, help me pls"></textarea> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @Lain I have the below code snippet running:- <div class="formFields quickPaste">
   <div>
    <textarea id="quickPasteArea" name="quickPaste" placeholder="Paste parts list here"></textarea>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS and frameworks in a [mcve]

Comment: I don't understand the problem

Comment: Hi @FlashThunder, I have a text area in my page which should ideally accept say 10 lines of data(comma separated data), eg:, 1234,10,Hello        But when I am done typing the first line, and I hit enter, it should take me to the next line allowing me to type the next line of input. But it is not allowing that. Instead I get a console error saying 'Uncaught type error- cannot read properties of null undefined 'children'

Comment: You have NO code in your question!

Comment: @ZareenIshtiaque you need to give javascript code that causes that, without that we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rows="number_of_rows" and cols if needed

```html
<div class="formFields quickPaste">
  <div> <textarea id="quickPasteArea" rows="4" cols="50" name="quickPaste" placeholder="Paste parts list here"></textarea> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried this. It didn't work out well

Comment: @ZareenIshtiaque You are literally not giving us ANYTHING to help us help you. "didn't work out well" is not a problem statement

Comment: Hi, Once inserting the first line of input- On click on Enter, I am presented with this error in the console:- abc.js?chupsVersion:32819 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children')
    at pf.quickOrder.validateInput (abc.js?chupsVersion:32819:30)

Comment: I have this snippet of code for children sibling logic :-                                                                   if(evt.nextElementSibling.children[0] != undefined){
    if(evt.nextElementSibling.children[0].childElementCount == 1 && evt.value.length > 5

Comment: UPDATE THE QUESTION! with relevant CSS AND PLUGINS/FRAMEWORK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `<textarea></textarea>` tag for that.

```html
<textarea name="textarea"
    rows="5" cols="30"
    placeholder="Comment text."></textarea>
```